# Xamarin Forms CollectionView Tap Gesture or Selection Changed not working

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Xamarin.Forms my issue is atleast present on android.

I have a collectionview which is using grouping. I would like to make each collectionview group be clickable. I have tried adding a tapGesture recogniser to StackLayout in second data template, Label in top data template and the CollectionView itself, I have also tried them both as tapped and command. And lastly, I have tried SelectionChanged on the collectionView.

Clicking anywhere on the collectionview hits no breakpoints in ViewModel or View.cs

I would like it so clicking on an item will provide a parameter of sorts to the ViewModel so it knows what item in the CollectionView was hit

This is my XAML, if someone could see what blunder I am making that would be awesome! Thank you

```
<CollectionView Grid.Row="1"  ItemsSource="{Binding ResponseCollection}" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="ResponseCollectionView_SelectionChanged" x:Name="ResponseCollectionView" IsGrouped="True" >

                <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <Label BackgroundColor="White" Padding="10,10,10,0" Text="{Binding Response}">
                        </Label>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ScrollView>
                            <Grid Padding="10" BackgroundColor="White">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">

                                    <Label TextColor="Red" Text="{Binding Statistic}"/>
                                    <Label TextColor="Red" Text="{Binding Amount}"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                                
                                <BoxView Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Gray" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></BoxView>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

            </CollectionView>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [relative binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings)

1. Add a name for the container (or ContentPage)
2. Use relative binding for your tap command binding

```
<StackLayout x:Name="PageView">
    <CollectionView>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ViewModelCommand, Source={x:Reference PageView}}" />
                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</StackLayout>
```

**Updated** to include the parameter:

```
<TapGestureRecognizer
    Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ViewModelCommand, Source={x:Reference PageView}}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you the click now works, is there a way to pass in however the collection view item?

Comment: @SamuelJames check my updated answer, and remember to set the same item object as the parameter of the command.

Comment: The issue is it only gives back the one instance of the listview not my entire collectionview (including the items in the listview) As I need the group heading label and all listview Items

Comment: That sounds like [Collection + expander](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/186053/collectionview-group-expander)

Comment: I have tried by referencing the collectionview but SelectedItem is always null, Ok let me have a look into that thank you

Comment: Maybe I thought it wrong way, "one instance of the listview not my entire collectionview", is it a nested list or just grouping of the collectionview? And the whole list should be in your viewmodel already, we normally need the single selected item while tapping.

Comment: I have a group, the header is Response and the items attached to the group are a list of objects. When I click on an item in the collection view which would be one group, I want the click events to know of the Response and all List items for that group. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I ended up adding the parameter to the response text as this is unique I could then use this to get Restrictions from viewmodel!