# Xamarin CollectionView.GestureRecognizers not working?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a collection view that I want to do something when someone clicks on it (regardless if they select an Item, or even if there are no items). Basically if the user taps anywhere in the collection view I want to run a command. But I can't seem to get it to fire. Is this simply not supported by collection view?

```
<CollectionView x:Name="addedContactCollection" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" ItemsSource="{Binding  RecentComments}" SelectionMode="None">
            <CollectionView.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                                Command="{Binding CollectionTapped}">
                </TapGestureRecognizer>
            </CollectionView.GestureRecognizers>
```

Running the exact same gesture code on any other item seems to work fine. I assume its because collection view propagates the gesture to the items.

So is the right thing to do to wrap the collection view in something? or is there a property to collection view that will make this work?

Comment: attaching a gesture to the overall view would block your ability to select any individual row.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Why can't you attach the command to something in the `DataTemplate`?

Comment: @Jason Yes that is exactly what I want. I don't want to execute on any selected item

Comment: @ewerspej I assumed that would not work if there were no items in your collection view... Will try that

Comment: Yes, if the collection is empty, that won't work, but then your `CollectionView` won't render anything to begin with, either.

Comment: I'd try putting it in a layout and attaching a gesture to the layout

Comment: @ewerspej well it will still render its own view. Like if you set the background color, its still has its own view space

Comment: @Jason that didn't work for some reason. It looks like it just eats all the touch gestures  :-(

Comment: You can refer to the answer in the thread: ["Xamarin Forms CollectionView Tap Gesture or Selection Changed not working".](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68088750/xamarin-forms-collectionview-tap-gesture-or-selection-changed-not-working)